# Multiple UV Maps For 1 Object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, vertex-groups, vector-mapping

I have a problem that is occurring when I try to add multiple UV maps to one object. When I select a vertex group and unwrap, it works fine, unwrapping just that vertex group to a UV map. The problem is when I select another vertex group and make a new UV map then unwrap, it unwraps that vertex group, but in the UV editor it still shows the previous unwrap in that UV map. I know that it is not just showing up because of "keep mesh in sync" because when I select the previous UV map, the vertex group from the UV map made after that one does not show up in the previous one. It seems every time I make a new UV map, the UV map from before automatically shows up in the new one, regaurdless of using a different texture. I am also making sure that I have just the faces that I want selected when I unwrap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should keep one UV map, but create two materials. Assign the wanted faces to each material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender allows multiple images to be assigned in one UV Map. If I'm not mistaken you want one set of UVs, just across multiple textures. To do this select only the faces you want to use a specific texture, and in the UV/Image Editor click the "browse image to be linked" rollout, and select the that texture.

[image: example of texture rollout]

This will map any faces you have currently selected to that texture in the "textured" viewport shading mode.

Alternatively, in the UV/Image Editor use "image > open image" to open an image file not already linked to the blender scene, or the + icon to make an internal image.

If you want to render this object or export it to another application, not just view it in the "textured" viewport, you will need to assign a material to your faces, and assign your texture to that material.