# How do you merge 2 identical meshes with different UV maps?

Tags: mesh, uv

I've two identical objects with two different UV maps and therefore two different textures. The UV map of the first object is for the normal map, the UV map of the second object is for the color input. Is there a way to combine these two UV maps on one object, so i can use both textures on one object?

Comment: Under Object Data Properties > UV Maps, you can see that a single object can have multiple UV maps, so yes, you can use both textures at once on the same object.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76553/multiple-uv-maps-for-1-object might answer your question.

Comment: It worked, thank you!